# How do you change the maximum count of a semaphore after you've created it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

If you have a semaphore that is being used to restrict access to a shared resource or limit the number of concurrent actions, what is the locking algorithm to be able to change the maximum value of that semaphore once it's in use?

**Example 1**

In `NSOperationQueue`, there is a property named `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. This value can be changed after the queue has been created. The documentation notes that changing this value doesn't affect any operations already running, but it does affect pending jobs, which presumably are waiting on a lock or semaphore to execute.

Since that semaphore is potentially being held by pending operations, you can just replace it with one with a new count. So another lock must be needed in the change somewhere, but where?

**Example 2:**

In most of Apple's Metal sample code, they use a semaphore with an initial count of 3 to manage in-flight buffers. I'd like to experiment changing that number while my application is running, just to see how big of a difference it makes. I could tear down the entire class that uses that semaphore and then rebuild the Metal pipeline, but that's a bit heavy handed. Like above, I'm curious how I can structure a sequence of locks or semaphores to allow me to swap out that semaphore for a different one while everything is running.

My experience is with Grand Central Dispatch, but I'm equally interested in a C++ implementation that might use those locking or atomic constructs.

*I should add that I'm aware I can technically just make unbalanced calls to `signal` and `wait` but that doesn't seem right to me. Namely, whatever code that is making these changes needs to be able to block itself if `wait` takes awhile to reduce the count...*

Comment: Semaphores don't have a maximum count, only a current count (which starts at the initial count). The behavior of the code in terms of signalling and waiting is the only thing which controls that count and the semantics of how that affects control over whatever resources the semaphore is coordinating access to. In my opinion, "extraneous" calls to signal and wait are the correct approach. If you want to decrease the count without potentially blocking, dispatch the wait(s) to a concurrent queue.

Comment: Agreed, poor choice of terminology... Increasing the count seems pretty straight forward but not so much with decreasing the count. If you have a semaphore with initial count of 3 and then fire off 1,000 "jobs", 3 of the jobs will start executing while 997 block on the semaphore. If you then try and decrease the semaphore count to 2 by simply making an unbalanced call to wait, isn't it possible for all 997 jobs to potentially acquire the semaphore before? Which implies that pending jobs might still run with the "old" concurrency count, which is not how I read `NSOperationQueue's` footnote.

Comment: You won't be able to reproduce `NSOperationQueue`'s semantics with a simple semaphore. `NSOperationQueue` controls the execution of operations. The operations themselves are not already running, but blocked on permission to continue. In your example of firing off 1,000 tasks, many of them start, get to the wait, and block before continuing. But that's different from not having been started. The best you can do with the semaphore scheme to reduce the number that get to continue is to reduce the count on a highest-priority queue. Otherwise, use or reimplement `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: This insight is what the original motivation for this question was. I definitely don't want to re-implement GCD or `NSOperationQueue` myself, but I would always like to learn more about how some things are done. That NSOperationQueue doesn't use the semaphore pattern described above is what I had concluded, and thus was wondering how they had architected such a feature. It's for learning, not for production... :) Thanks for the comments, always appreciated.

Comment: So, you're now asking how `NSOperationQueue` is (or might be) implemented?

Comment: Now the I appreciate that `NSOperationQueue` doesn't just use a simple semaphore for controlling execution then yes. But knowing that sort of answers my original question. To "change the value" of a semaphore, I just track unbalanced `wait/signal` calls to it as I originally thought. The answer to how `NSOperationQueue` does it is that it doesn't use a single sempahore. Knowing that, I can probably come up with a few design patterns that would work now that I know I'm not looking for a simple "semaphore trick". Thanks Ken.